# Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I click button visit store, I'm getting the above error. My react version is `17.0.2` & react-dom version is `17.0.2` & react-router-dom version is `5.3.0`.

Index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Router from "./components/Router";
import "./css/style.css";
render(<Router />, document.querySelector("#main"));
```

Router.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import StorePicker from "./StorePicker";
import App from "./App";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";

const Router = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={StorePicker} />
  <Route path="/store/:storeId" component={App} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
    );
  export default Router;
```

When I console log this.myInput.value.value, I'm getting undefined. Please help.

StorePicker.js file

```
import { getFunName } from "../helpers";
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
 myInput = React.createRef();

 goToStore = (event) => {
   // 1. Stop the form from submitting
   event.preventDefault();
   // 2. Get the text from the input
   const storeName = this.myInput.value.value;
   // 3. Change the page to /store/whatever user has entered
   this.props.history.push(`/store/${storeName}`);
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
       <h2>Please enter a store name</h2>
       <input
         type="text"
         required
         ref={this.myInput}
         placeholder="Store Name"
         defaultValue={getFunName()}
       />
       <button type="submit">Visit Store </button>
     </form>
   );
 }
}

export default StorePicker;
```

This one is app.js file, And I have included component inside Route.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Order from "./Order";
import Inventory from "./Inventory";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="catch-of-the-day">
        <div className="menu">
          <Header tagline="Fresh Seafood Market" age="21" />
        </div>
        <Order />
        <Inventory />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And I have created NotFound() component & included the same inside Route.js file.

```
const NotFound = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Not Found!!!</h2>
  </div>
);

export default NotFound();
```

Comment: `this.myInput` is a react ref, so it should be something like `this.myInput.current.value`. Which route has a component that isn't a React component? You included `StorePicker` and it's certainly a React component. What of `App` and `NotFound`?

Comment: Shouldn't it should just be `export default NotFound` without the parantheses. Remove that and give it a shot. Also as mentioned in above comment it should be `this.myInput.current.value`

Comment: I agree with @Singh3y... I have copy/pasted your code into a codesandbox and see no such issue, but declared all the components in the same file. This `NotFound` export is certainly incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Singh3yIssue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DrewReese has been resolved.